# PHP: How do I ORDER BY total of 3 fields in Table?

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 fields in TABLE `HTR`

- Field `H`
- Field `T`
- Field `R`

Values:

- Field `H` is worth 10 points per qty
- Field `T` is worth 1 point per qty
- Field `R` is worth 5 points per qty

So... what I need is a query to MULTIPLY each field data by the points, then add all points AS total_points, and ORDER BY total_points.

Like this...

```
Field H = 100
Field T = 50
Field R = 20

H = 100*10 (1000)
T =  50*1  (50)
R =  20*5  (100)

Total_Points = 1150
```

Now I need a query to display everything ORDERED BY total_points.

Answer (score 4):

```
ORDER BY (H*10+T*1+R*5)
```

If any of `H,T,R` can be `NULL`, you also need to handle it properly. For example `ORDER BY (IFNULL(H,0)*19+...` (assuming you use mysql)

```
SELECT (IFNULL(H,0)*10+IFNULL(T,0)*1+IFNULL(R,0)*5)  as Total_Points
FROM HTR
ORDER BY Total_Points
```

You can also use `COALESCE` instead of `IFNULL`, many more RDMS support it in contrast to `IFNULL`

Comment: Wow a1ex07, instant fix! Thank you VERY MUCH!